# Using c# how can I programmatically check if a folder exists on my reporting server

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I Have spent hours looking but without any success.

I am programmatically creating snap shots of reports in SSRS using c# which creates report folders.  The reports are created in these folders but to prevent errors occurring I am deleting the whole folder structure and then re-creating the reports to prevent SSRS throwing an exception.

I am using ReportingService2010.

```
ReportingService2010.DeleteItem(deleteFolderPath);
```

…

```
ReportingService2010.CreateFolder(folder, parentFolder, null);
```

-- This is the line where I need to check if the folder and report exist

```
var ret = CheckExist(linkedReportName, newParent);

var param = GetReportParameters(existingReportPath);

ReportingService2010.SetItemParameters(existingReportPath, param);
```

-- If I do not delete the folder structure the error will be thrown after this in a try/Catch

```
ReportingService2010.CreateLinkedItem(linkedReportName, newParent, existingReportPath, props);
```

I need to add a method to see if the report and report folder has already been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible alternative is to directly work with the path, type, and parentid fields of the Catalog table in your report server database.  If you open SQL Server and look at the table, it should be pretty clear what you need to do.

You can use C# to run a SQL command such as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATALOG WHERE PATH LIKE '%TheFolderNameImLookingFor%'
```

If the count is greater than zero, then the folder exists.

You can vary this for your needs.  Folder items have a type of 1; Report items have a type of 2, so you can use this to distinguish between reports and folders.

Comment: I tend to work in the other direction, personally.  If I can get what I want directly from the data, I do so.  If I can't, I go wandering through the vast and murky hallways of the .Net framework to see if I can find something I can use.  :)

Comment: How _programmatically__ get the users (permissions, roles) about **Folder** in ***SSRS server***  ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the nicest way is [ReportService2010.GetItemType()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemtype.aspx) method. This returns a string ([ReportingService2010.ListItemTypes()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listitemtypes.aspx) method), including possible values `"Unknown"` for non-existent (rather than throwing an exception) or `"Folder"` for a folder.

Answer (score 0):

How to delete folders if they exist using `ListChildren`;

```
        var items = ReportingService2010.ListChildren(parentFolder, false);
        if (items.Where(x => x.TypeName == "Folder").Any(x => x.Name == folder))
        {
            ReportingService2010.DeleteItem(folder, parentFolder, null);
        }
```

Comment: How _programmatically__ get the users (permissions, roles) about **Folder** in ***SSRS server***  ?

Answer (score -4):

[Directory.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might work for you.

```
if (Directory.Exists(folderString))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Don't forget the `System.IO` namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

**UPDATE**: In the future, if you're looking for a file, you can do the same thing with `File.Exists()`, which is also in the `System.IO` namespace.

Answer (score -5):

```
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    ReportingService2010.CreateFolder(folder, parentFolder, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  These are great if you need to find folders or files on your c:\ drive but I am looking for the code that checks to see if the folder exists on the Report Servicer – where the reports get deployed to which would be the TargetReportFolder and TargetServerURL.  I have looked at ReportingService2010 .FindItems() but I am not sure if this is correct.  
Apologies if I was not specific in my earlier description.

Comment: @user1221584: you were specific enough just fine. These answerers read only the question title. FWIW `FindItems` seems like you're on the right track to me.